# getting error about objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {attributes}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. I check out for solution but couldnt find can you guys help me what cause the error. and if you mind can you also give some explanation about this error...

```
const customData = [
  {
    attributes: {
      OBJECTID: 23,
      CITY_ID: 1,
      CITY_NAME: "NEW YORK",
      ILCE_CODE: 1103    
    }
  },
  {
    attributes: {
      OBJECTID: 36,
      CITY_ID: 33,
      CITY_NAME: "TORONTO",
      ILCE_CODE: 2048
    }
  }
];

const Form = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const [cityData, setCityData] = useState({
    value: null,
    arrayValue: []
  });

  const updateFormData = event =>
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });

  const selectMultiOption = value =>
  setCityData({
      arrayValue: value
    });

  const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = formData;
  const { value, arrayValue } = setCityData;

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        value={firstName}
        onChange={e => updateFormData(e)}
        placeholder="First name"
        type="text"
        name="firstName"
        required
      />
some other inputs here...
      <Picky
        value={arrayValue}
        options={customData}
        onChange={selectMultiOption}
        open={true}
        valueKey="CITY_CODE"
        labelKey="CITY_NAME"
        multiple={true}
        includeSelectAll={true}
        includeFilter={true}
        dropdownHeight={600}
      />

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you post the return of Picky?

Comment: why do you have nested objects ? `[ { {} } , { {} } ]` ? why not just `[{},{},{}]` ?

Comment: Its not working at all directly get this error

Comment: actuallt data comes from service like that

Comment: well i guess the problem lies here `options={customData}` ( or one of the problems ) . Either talk to the BE guys to send different data structure either change it yourself so you have `[{},{}]` not nested objects.

Answer (score 1):

(First SO answer in a while, so apologies in advance if something is not according to standards)

As Mihai T pointed out in the comments, it seems to be a problem with your `customData` variable value that is sent in as the `options` prop to the `Picky` component. I have no experience with Picky myself, but it appears that the prop `options` is expected to be a flat list if values in the default case. Changing your variable `customData` to

```
customData = [1,2,3]
```

resolves the problem when I test. Link to a CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-snowflake-7dzfh) (switch the `options` prop for the `Picky` component from `customData` to `customData2` to see the effect).

You probably either want to pre-process your `customData` before sending a flat list of values to the Picky component, or use the "Custom rendering" pattern described in the [react-picky docs](https://github.com/Aidurber/react-picky)